# Not Implemented at System.Data.Services.AstoriaRequestMessage.get_HttpVerb()

Tags: wcf

A WCF self-hosted app runs in a docker container with Full .Net FW.
While analyzing the log, I see a lot of log entries with error mentioned in the title.
All HTTP verbs in logs look standard.

Answer (score 2):

I've found that Self-hosted WCF service doesn't support the `OPTIONS` http verb.